# Access Denied in excel VBA when using web.send

Tags: vba, excel

I was checking the stock price in excel macro by using the following code. However, I received during "web.send"

> Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)':
>    Access is denied

Since it was fine until yesterday and there was no other information
so I just cannot figure out the reason.
Can anyone help to check this? Thank you very much.

```
Sub CheckIndex()

Sheets("Temp").Range("A:A").Clear

    Url = "https://www.google.com.hk/finance?q=INDEXHANGSENG:HSI"
    Set web = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    web.Open "get", Url, False
    web.send
    webdata = Split(web.responseText, vbLf)


    For J = 0 To UBound(webdata)
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Cells(J + 1, 1).NumberFormatLocal = "@" 
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").Cells(J + 1, 1).Value = webdata(J)
    Next J

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible that your IT changed some privilege of yours?

Comment: Try to use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`, `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` or `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` instead of `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`.

Comment: @omegastripes I can reproduce the OPs error, and using `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` or `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` fixes it.  (`MSXML2.XMLHTTP` still gives the error.)

Comment: IIRC that is due to the redirections handling differencies  between wininet and winhttp.

Comment: It works when using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP, Thank you very much!